# Print length of regex group with awk

Tags: regex, awk, replace

I am writing a script to replace a base URL in a database dump with another base URL (to transfer the DB contents of Wordpress to another host). Replacing the URL is the easy part (currently doing it with sed).

However, there is a problem with the values of Wordpress' options table, which stores strings in PHP serialized format, producing something like `...;s:6:\"abcdef\";s:3:\"zzz\";...` (variable type string, length 6 and 3, value "abcdef" and "zzz"). So whenever the length of the old and the new base URL differ, that option value won't be loaded, as the string length given does not match the length of the actual string anymore.

So that is the part where awk comes in: I am trying to match every string of the format `s:number:\"baseurl/some_path\"` and replace the number with the actual length of the `baseurl/some_path` string, to update the string length values.

The awk command I got so far is:

```
awk '{print gensub(/s:([0-9]+):\\"([^\\"]*)\\"/, sprintf("s:%d:\\\\\"%s\\\\\"", length("\\2"), "\\2"), "g") }' db_content_file
```

But this generates string lengths of 2, no matter what the actual string is, so I guess that `\2` gets passed to the length function literally, without replacing it with the string stored in `\2`. Is it somehow possible to enforce such a replacement? Or should I use another tool?

Comment: You need to do this in pieces I think. Find the string to replace and get its length and then replace it.

Comment: Could you give me a hint on how to do it in pieces - do I need some kind of loop and which functions would be relevant in that case? I never worked with awk before and it took me some hours to get to a basic substitution command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, semicolons can occur in valid URLs so simply using split() will not work.

So it looks like you'll either have to use PHP to unserialize and re-serialize, or parse the serialized string.  Based on your description, the following should do the job:

```
awk '
  # Recompute the string lengths in a serialization in which strings
  # are represented by segments such as: s:6:\"abcdef\";
  # WARNING: the array a is global
  function repopulate(s, a1,n) { 
    # match(string, regexp [, array])
    # a[1] is set to the substring matching the first parenthesized subexpresssion, etc
    n = match(s, /s:[0-9]+:\\"([^\\"]*)\\";(.*)/, a);
    if (n<=0) {return s;}
    a1=a[1]; 
    return substr(s,1,n-1) "s:" length(a1) ":\\\"" a1 "\\\";" repopulate(a[2])
  }

  { print repopulate($0) }'
```

Comment: This is the kind of solution I was looking for! Thank you! However, I had to do some optimization to avoid crashing, as there is a lot of data in the file that comes from the Wordpress feed and doesn't contain my URL anyway (some lines being around 100k characters long). So I grep every line first, to look for my URL and only perform the awk command on those that contain it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `gawk` you can use `match`

for example

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ match("s:22:\"baseurl/somepath\"", \
                    /s:([0-9]+):\"(.+)\"/,a);    \
              print length(a[2])}'


16
```

I guess you can take it from here...

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you could perform each from/to replacement in one step, like so:

```
awk -v from="http://one.com" -v to="http://two.two.org" '
  { from = "s:([0-9]+):\"" from "\";";
    to   = "s:" length(to) ":\"" to "\";";
    gsub(from, to);
    print; }'
```

This also has the advantage of not requiring a special awk, while retaining the advantage of not requiring the initial length specifications to be correct.

Comment: One problem I can see with this solution is that I don't know which path (`some_path` in my question) will be appended to the known base URL, so I don't know the final length, but only the length of the base URL _without_ the `some_path` part.